# Sending more than one HTTP status code in a script

Tags: http, http-headers, http-status-codes

More of a sanity check than anything else.

Do browsers always use the last HTTP status code that I send from my script?

For instance if I sent a 200 and then send a 404, will all browsers correctly handle the page as 404?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser will only ever receive one. The HTTP protocol does not permit multiple status codes.

If your script is trying to send several, then it's up to the server-side framework to handle that so that only one gets sent. Exactly what happens is going to depend on the framework in question.